# Check if getElementsByTagName() contains class attribute | Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have been trying to figure out how to determine whether an element found by its tag name contains a certain class.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work and I don't see why not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .mystyle {
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: coral;
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Click the button to add the "mystyle" class to DIV.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The classList property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

  <div id="myDIV">I am a DIV element</div>

  <table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
  </table>

  <p id="demo"><p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr").classList.contains("mystyle");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code should print `false` in the `<p id="demo"><p>` element but does not and throws the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByTagName("tr").classList.contains')

Does anyone know how to determine whether an element found by its tag name contains a certain class?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements (“getElements”, plural). Which `<tr>` do you want to check?

Comment: why not just do `!!document.querySelectorAll('tr.mystyle').length`?

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to:

```
!!document.querySelectorAll('tr.mystyle').length
```

The issue is that `getElementsByTagName("tr")` returns a NodeList, and a NodeList does not have a `.classList` attribute.  However, instead of iterating over that list, or only checking a single element, you can just check for the existance of an element that has that class, and then if there isn't one, `!!0` will become `false`, and `!!1` or more will become true.

Comment: `document.querySelector('tr.mystyle') !== null`

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` does not return a NodeList - it returns an HTMLCollection. (NodeLists returned by qSA are much easier to handle because they're not live, and can be directly `forEach`ed over)

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns collection. You have to loop through all the elements. Try with [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) like the following way:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("tr");
  x.forEach(function(el){
   var y = el.classList.contains("mystyle");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += ' ' + y;
  })  
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to add the "mystyle" class to DIV.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The classList property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div id="myDIV">I am a DIV element</div>

<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr class="mystyle"><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>

<p id="demo"><p>
```

Comment: So only the first row…?

Comment: Now it’s only the last row.

Comment: @Mamun Why is this only showing 3 outputs and not 9?